# How to rename folders in Python package without breaking SVN?

Tags: python, svn

I have a structure like this in my PyCharm project:

```
first_package
└───first_package
    └───first_file.py
secondpackage
└───secondpackage
    └───second_file.py
```

I want to remove the underscore from `first_package`, but this package is used in `secondpackage` (and others).

This should be a pretty straightforward task using PyCharm's refactoring tool, however, I'm pretty sure SVN is not going to like it if PyCharm renames both of the `first_package` directories to `firstpackage` without informing it first.

My understanding of SVN is that I should use `svn mv`, followed by `svn commit`, for changing the names of files/directories. The trouble is, if I do that I will have renamed the directories outside of PyCharm and then I will no doubt have some error-prone search-and-replace work to do.

Am I overlooking a simple solution?

Comment: Yes, if the simple solution is to move to mercurial or git.

Comment: JetBrains IDEs are typically very smart about this kind of stuff. Why don't you just try the refactoring feature and see what happens? Changes don't get "permanent" unless you decide to commit them.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206895765-Rename-refactoring-and-Subversion - it seems it should work OOB (if you integrate with SVN).

Comment: I wasn't brave enough to try with PyCharm. SVN is enough of a headache, without risking the chance of having to fix self-inflicted issues. As it was, I plumped for option 2 on @Stewart's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your original tree:

```
.
├── first_package
│   └── first_package
│       └── first_file.py
└── secondpackage
    └── secondpackage
        └── second_file.py
```

Go ahead and let your refactoring tool turn your tree into:

```
.
├── firstpackage
│   └── firstpackage
│       └── first_file.py
└── secondpackage
    └── secondpackage
        └── second_file.py
```

Then `svn status` gives:

```
$ svn status
!       first_package
!       first_package/first_package
!       first_package/first_package/first_file.py
?       firstpackage
```

At this point if we try `svn mv` to record what happened in SVN we get an error:

```
$ svn mv first_package firstpackage
svn: E155010: Directory '/tmp/tmp.wlyfVrQasv/repo/firstpackage' is not under version control
```

That's because `svn mv` wants to perform the move action.  It doesn't just record something that already happened.

## Option 1 (simple)

In this solution, you will lose your SVN history.  If you don't care about history, and the refactoring is actually super complicated, then this might be the simple option.

1. Use `svn add` on anything which is marked by `svn status` as `?`.
2. Use `svn del` on anything which is marked by `svn status` as `!`.

## Option 2 (complete)

This solution is better as it retains history.

Leave your code as-is, but undo the file-structure/name changes manually, then use SVN to redo them.  In this case we start with the root of the project:

```
$ svn status | grep -v /
!       first_package
?       firstpackage
```

To apply this:

```
$ mv firstpackage first_package
$ svn mv first_package firstpackage
A         firstpackage
D         first_package
D         first_package/first_package
D         first_package/first_package/first_file.py
```

If we check `svn status` and look for the next level of `!` and `?` (and filter out the py file) we see:

```
$ svn status | grep '^[!?]' | grep -v py
!       firstpackage/first_package
?       firstpackage/firstpackage
```

Let's handle that next:

```
$ mv firstpackage/firstpackage firstpackage/first_package
$ svn mv firstpackage/first_package firstpackage/firstpackage
A         firstpackage/firstpackage
D         firstpackage/first_package
D         firstpackage/first_package/first_file.py
```

Now we have the directory structure you want and SVN is happy:

```
$ svn status
D       first_package
        > moved to firstpackage
A  +    firstpackage
        > moved from first_package
D  +    firstpackage/first_package
        > moved to firstpackage/firstpackage
A  +    firstpackage/firstpackage
        > moved from firstpackage/first_package
```

Now you're ready to `svn commit`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive solution. I went with option 2 as I definitely wanted (needed) to retain the history.